# Computing a circle from a given set with a tangent line condition

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, tangent-line

I was asked to compute the circles' equations from the set

$$x^2 + y^2 -3x + (k-6)y + (9-3k)=0$$

that fulfill the following request: the circles must be tangent to the line

$$x+y-3=0$$

I started to compute

$$
\begin{cases}
x^2 + y^2 -3x + (k-6)y + (9-3k)=0\\
x+y-3=0
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
x^2 + y^2 -3x + (k-6)y + (9-3k)=0\\
x=3-y
\end{cases}
$$

obtaining

$$
\begin{cases}
2y^2 +(k-3)y +(9-3k)=0\\
x=3-y
\end{cases}
$$

Now, in order to obtain a tangent line to the circle, I must put the condition $\Delta=0$, yielding

$$(k-3)^2-8(9-3k)=0$$

and so

$$k_1=3, \quad k_2=-24$$

So I have the circles, by replacing $k$:

$$x^2 + y^2 -3x -3y =0$$

and

$$x^2 + y^2 -3x -30y + 81=0$$

while the solutions reported were $$x^2+y^2-3x-5y+8=0$$ and $$x^2+y^2-3x-13y+32=0$$

Could anyone tell me where I am getting wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Once you spotted the obvious solution 
$k=3$, you can factor
$$(k-3)^2-8(9-3k)=(k-3)\left[k-3+24\right]=(k-3)(k+21)$$

and so the second solution is $21$, not $24$.

---

There is another mistake earlier when you develop $x^2=(y-3)^2$, it looks like you implicitly wrote $(y-3)^2=y^2+3^2$, forgetting the rectangular term.

Answer (score 0):

You have occoured in an error when you say: "obtaining: " $$\begin{cases}
2y^2 +(k-3)y +(9-3k)=0\\
x=3-y
\end{cases}$$
You should have obtained: $$\begin{cases}
2y^2 +(k-9)y +(9-3k)=0\\
x=3-y
\end{cases}$$

From here: $(k-9)^2-8(9-3k)=0$ and $k^2+6k+9=0$, so $k=-3$. The equation of the circle is: $x^2+y^2-3x-9y+18=0$.

Here the graph:

[image]

The solution $x^2+y^2-3x-5y+8=0$ is impossible because $9-3k=8$ ($k=\frac{1}{3}$) and $k-6=5$ ($k=11$) that is impossible.

Comment: ....but this result continues not to be equal to the solution reported in the book.... :/

Comment: What's the solution?

Comment: $$x^2+y^2-3x-5y+8=0$$ and $$x^2+y^2-3x-13y+32=0$$

Comment: The first solution is impossible as shown above.

Comment: I will check again the data....thanks....

Comment: Also the second equation is impossible, in fact: $k-6=-13$ so $k=-7$, but if you substitute in $9-3k=32$ you see this is impossible because $30\neq32$. There is only a solution when $k=3$.